# adding listener to a Firebase query after querying another child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase structure: [image]

I want to make a notification every time a new comment is made on a user's post. To do this I have to listen to all the comments for all the media made by the user. the createdBy/uid is a unique ID associated with this user. I can get the media just fine with:

```
 let ref = DatabaseReference.media.reference()
 let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "createdBy/uid").queryEqual(toValue: (self.currentUser!.uid))
    query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
        if !self.myMedia.contains(media) {
            self.myMedia.insert(media, at: 0)
```

where myMedia is an array of dictionaries. To attach a listener to the comments, I would have to loop through the array and attach a listener to the comments node because the media uid would be in the dictionaries. Is this possible? If not is there a better way to accomplish my task?

Comment: Stepping back a second, any client side approach is only going to give a notification when a user is actively using your app. Is that what you want? A standard way of looking at such a problem would be to have firebase cloud code listen for comment events and publish a FCM message to any users who you want to contact

Comment: I want to have a UILabel which counts the number of new comments so it would have to be persistent. For Firebase i've only worked on the client side though.

Comment: `media` is a dictionary (`[String : Any]`). I'm not a Swift expert, but I doubt this will work `self.myMedia.contains(media)`, unless you have a quite intelligent custom `contains` method.

Comment: it already works because I taught the class to conform to the Equatable protocol